# What is use of operators and alerts in SQL server management studio?

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone explain why and where to use operators and alerts in SQL server management studio?

Answer (score 1):

Operators and alerts are intended to support SQL Server jobs, which in turn are managed by the SQL Server Agent.

Lets say you had a SQL Server instance that processed a significant number of jobs. You may want to assign a particular operator responsiblity for certain jobs and so choose to inform them of the status of these jobs i.e. a member of the Finance Team might be responsible for a job that produces invoices.

The following reference details how to create operators.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1523

Hope this makes sense but do please feel free to contact me directly if you need further assistance.

Cheers, John

Comment: Hi 
i am not getting the email notification after job executed.how to resolve this.....plz help me...

Comment: Are you refering to 'Failure Notification' within a SQL job? If so then no email is returned when a job successfully completes.